# Custom Values in Manifest.json for Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is it allowed to have custom values saved in manifest.json for a Chrome extension?
Because it is json, I want to save some information in manifest.json, especially because Chrome API is available for Opera, I need some distinguish data.

Does Chrome store complain if there is any custom data in manifest.json?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to put it in the manifest instead of another json file?

Comment: There is non-standard data available for Opera and other Chrome API compatible browsers. So rather than creating different files, I thought to keep distinguish data in manifest.json so that I can have global source code   that may work for all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not allowed to use custom values in Chrome Extension manifest.json file. You can refer below given link. @John

```
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest
```

You can only use those parameters in manifest.json. If you will use others parameters rather than allowed, it will throw an error at time of importing chrome extension.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest